# How to add_action to Woocommerce hook?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I simply want to add an action to an existing Woocommerce hook (woocommerce_after_cart in this case). After adding a function with `add_action()` and loading the page back up, my function doesn't run. Not until I manually `do_action()` does my function finally run. I just want to know why when I add the action originally, it's not being acknowledged.

I've already checked out Wordpress codex for hooks and seems like I'm doing everything correct. I'm adding the action in a custom theme, not `functions.php` but I've tried that too.

Full thing looks like this:

```
function abc() {
   print_r("hello world");
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_cart','abc');
```

Hello world does not print on page load, only after I call `do_action()`, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for any `add_action()` to work a `do_action()` must be called.

The `woocommerce_after_cart` action is called in the template "/cart/cart.php"
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_after_cart

In your theme or child theme do you have the file "/woocommerce/cart/cart.php"?
It could be that the WooCommerce cart template is being overridden and that the template does not have the `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart' ); ?>` call.

I have tested your abc function and it works in a vanilla out of the box install of Woo and WP.

You need to add the `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart' ); ?>` action to the cart.php template file.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm not overwriting any templates and the `do_action()` is in the originally template. I've changed my perspective on how I approach my cart page after reading your answer so while it didn't technically answer my question, it certainly helped me get there.